# Atributo "multiple" da tag <select> não funciona

Tags: html, html-select, multiple

Atributo `multiple` da tag `<select>` não funciona, só é possível selecionar uma única opção. Estou usando o Chrome.

```
<h4>From</h4>
    <div>
        <select name="sites-list" size="7" multiple>
            <option value="site-1" />SITE
            <option value="site-2" selected />SITE
            <option value="site-3" />SITE
            <option value="site-4" />SITE
            <option value="site-5" />SITE
            <option value="site-6" selected />SITE
            <option value="site-7" />SITE
            <option value="site-8" />SITE
            <option value="site-9" />SITE
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Testei o código e funcionou. Vc está utilizando o control para selecionar mais de uma opção?

Comment: Não sabia que devia utilizar control; 
Agora que sei, isso levanta uma questão, eu necessito criar uma lista onde o usuario poderá selecionar mais de uma opção, então seria possivel criar uma lista de checkbox com uma barra de rolagem (a lista é bem grande)

Comment: Embora o seu HTML funcione, eu ainda sugeriria colocar o texto dentro das tags `option`, como: `<option value="site-2" selected>SITE</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para selecionar mais opções do que a selecionada tem de pressionar CTRL, ou Apple (Mac), e depois clicar na opção.

Se quiser fazer um efeito tipo *toggle* a cada clic é possível, porém [a solução mais obvia não funciona muito bem](http://jsfiddle.net/7n8nnjus/1/). É preciso um *hack*. Procurei também no SOen ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8641729/2256325) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12585863/2256325)) mas as soluções que já lá estavam eram inconsistentes. Deixei esta resposta lá também.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51p7ocLw/

**Nota:** Esta solução possibilita clicar nas opções sem precisar de pressionar no CTRL, mas substitui o select no DOM. É um método algo adressivo pois vai quebrar oscultadores de evento se tiver algum amarrado ao `select`.

```js
window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // toggle selection
        if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) el.removeAttribute('selected');
        else el.setAttribute('selected', '');

        // hack para corrigir comportamento inconsistente
        var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
    }
}
```

```html
<h4>From</h4>

<div>
    <select name="sites-list" size="7" multiple>
        <option value="site-1">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-2" selected>SITE</option>
        <option value="site-3">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-4">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-5">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-6" selected>SITE</option>
        <option value="site-7">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-8">SITE</option>
        <option value="site-9">SITE</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Está funcionando normalmente, acontece que o usuário precisa manter a tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressionada enquanto seleciona os itens. Também funciona mantendo o botão do mouse pressionado enquanto passa o cursor sobre as opções. Faça o teste:

```css
/* somente visualização */
select{border: 2px solid #ccc;width:250px;height:200px}
```

```html
<select multiple name='sites[]'>
    <option value='site-a'>site a</option>
    <option value='site-b'>site b</option>
    <option value='site-c'>site c</option>
    <option value='site-d'>site d</option>
</select>
```

Outra solução pode ser utilizar algum plugin como o [MultiSelect](http://loudev.com/):

---

Quanto a pergunta feita nos comentários:

> Eu necessito criar uma lista onde o usuário poderá selecionar mais de uma opção, então seria possível criar uma lista de checkbox com uma barra de rolagem?

[Essa pergunta no StackOverflow-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option) cita um plugin chamado "UI MultiSelect Widget", [nessa página](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#animations) há alguns exemplos do que é possível fazer com ele.

Na minha opinião nem é necessário a inclusão de um script só para exibir um 'check'. Uma implementação simples somente com CSS:

```css
/* somente visualização */
select{border: 2px solid #ccc;width:250px;height:200px}

option:before { content: "☐ " }
option:checked:before { content: "☑ " }
```

```html
<select multiple name='sites[]'>
  <option value='site-a'>site a</option>
  <option value='site-b'>site b</option>
  <option value='site-c'>site c</option>
  <option value='site-d'>site d</option>
  <option value='site-e'>site e</option>
</select>
```

A grande vantagem é que a personalização se torna mais fácil mesmo tendo pouco conhecimento em CSS. Para ilustrar, um exemplo utilizando duas imagens: [image: !checked] e [image: checked] para opções selecionadas:

```css
option:before{ margin-right: 5px;content:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHKSN.png') }
option:checked:before { content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjCFU.png') }
```

```html
<select multiple name='sites[]'>
    <option value='site-a'>site a</option>
    <option value='site-b'>site b</option>
    <option value='site-c'>site c</option>
</select>
```